# Regular Expressions of two alternate patterns in single string

Tags: regex

I'm beginner in regular expressions, so your help will be very big for me.
I have this pattern string:

```
@"^\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d$"
```

which matches phone numbers only in this format: (555) 555-5555
but what I really need is the sequence to be followed, not the exact number of characters and positions. So I need the following sequence:

1. (
2. numbers
3. )
4. empty space
5. numbers
6. -
7. numbers

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+` instead of fixed number of characters?

```
@"^\(\d+\) \d+-\d+$"
```

Answer (score 2):

So, something like this?

```
^\(\d+\)\s*\d+-\d+

1 Open Paren
2 Numbers
3 Close Paren
4 Space
5 Numbers
6 Dash
7 Numbers
```

EDIT: Added the (none or more) quantifier to the space after the close paren

Comment: @dex, you might even place a `+` after `\s` so that two (or more) space chars also result in a match.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\d{x,y}` to represent a sequence of numbers at least x long and at most y long. Example:

```
@"^\(\d{1,3}\) \d{3,5}-\d{4,6}$"
```

For more details see [Regex Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: thanks to you too for the code and explanation... today I had a fast lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care how many numbers are in the area code, or the number, you can use this:

```
^\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\)\s*\d+\s*-\s*\d+\s*$
```

This allows for any amount of white space (including no white space) around the parentheses and dash, and at the beginning and end of the data.

If you do care how many numbers, use `\d{1,3}`, for example, instead of `\d+`. This allows for 1-3 digits in one place.